# When i open android studio, it says "Missing essential plugin: org.jetbrains.android Please reinstall Android Studio from scratch."

Tags: android

Recently, my android studio was working fine, however, yesterday when i opened android studio it said

```
"Missing essential plugin:

  org.jetbrains.android

Please reinstall Android Studio from scratch."
```

i Have tried installing many times, but still nothing happens.I even tried it running as an administrator. but then also nothing happens.
And the answers from the previous questions, i don't understand that where we have to past the links.(the C:users one...).
pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete this file:

```
Users\.AndroidStudio4.0\config\disabled_plugins.txt
```

or delete config folder completely if not work

Comment: where to find this file?(Users\.AndroidStudio4.0\config\disabled_plugins.txt
)

Comment: and sorry to ask, (as i am a newto android studio), where is config folder??

Comment: in windows driver -> users -> your username -> .androidStudio...(version of your android studio)

Comment: yaaaa!!! i finally found it and the problem is solved. thank you so much.......

Answer (score 0):

yes need to delete this file

file name is -disabled_plugins.txt

```
C:\Users\your_user_name_folder\.AndroidStudio4.0\config\disabled_plugins.txt
```

go to c drive and your user-folder and there you will find this location

Comment: thank You so much!!!!! the problem has been solved.

Comment: please upvote the answer so others will get the solution for the same problem

Comment: The path on my install of Windows 10 is:
C:\Users\<<your user name here>>\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio<<version number here>>

Also, it's probably not necessary to delete the file; simply remove the disabled plugin (probably Kotlin).